# C# Call SP Oracle return only header without data?

Tags: c#, oracle

I had:

```
PROCEDURE GET_1(
  cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN  
  OPEN cv_1 FOR SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; 
END;

PROCEDURE GET_2(
  cv_2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN  
  GET_1(cv_2); 
END;

var conn = new OracleConnection(ConnStr);
conn.Open();
var cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "GET_2";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.BindByName = true;
var orlPara = new List<OracleParameter>();
var cv_2 = new OracleParameter("cv_2", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
orlPara.Add(cv_2);

cmd.Parameters.AddRange(orlPara.ToArray());
var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
return ds;
```

When I run in SQL Developer `GET_2` it return result, but when I call `GET_2` using C# only header return without data, so what do I need to do?

Comment: Please include the C# code you're using

Comment: What is a "header?"

Comment: Not clear what you mean, but perhaps you just have to skip `adapter.Fill(ds);` Try `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: its columm's name